# Wi-Fi could not be joined, error -3902

Tags: macos, wifi

Sudently I can't connect to the wify at home anymore from my mac (all other devices are ok).

When trying to connect I get the dialog:

```
The Wi-Fi network "My_Wifi" could not be joined.

Try moving closer to your wireless router. Alternatively, run Wireless Diagnostics to troubleshoot.
```

And on the logs from `/private/var/log/wifi.log`:

```
Info: <airportd[51]> Failed to associate to WI-Fi network My_Wifi on interface en0, returned error code -3902
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that rebooting either the router and or the computer solves the problem. Why it happens I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to try to get Wifi working again.

- Reboot the router that serves your network. This router may have an integral Wifi radio, or a Wifi radio may be attached with a separate device. If so, reboot the wifi device, too.
- On the Mac itself, go to System Preferences > Network > Wifi and make sure the network you are trying to connect to is top on the list of Preferred Networks. It is a 'best practice' when Wifi problems come up to delete *all* the Wifi networks you have saved, and recreate the ones you need.